# Update Parent State from Child Component and send back response to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components,

Component A -

```
const handleLike(id) {
.....
handle the logic for the button and setting the state
}

<ComponentB handleLike={handleLike}/>
```

Component B -

```
return(
    <>
        <button onclick={props.handleLike("123")}/>
    </>
)

<ComponentB handleLike={handleLike}/>
```

This code works, but it changes the state in the Component A and the state is not updated in the Component B

How can this be solved?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example and share the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Component A -

```
const[likeId,setLikeId]= useState(like)
const handleLike(id) {
  .....
   handle the logic for the button and setting the state
  setLikeId(id)
}

<ComponentB likeId={likeId} handleLike={handleLike}/>
```

Component B -

```
const { likeId }=props
return(
<>
    <button onclick={props.handleLike("123")}/>
</>
)
```

Comment: You can directly pass both 'likeId' and 'setLikeId' as props to child.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useState in your parent component, handle callback from child, update the state, and pass the state to child component like this:

```
const ComponentA= () => {
   const [likes, setLikes] = useState('')

   const handleLikeCallback(id) {
       setLikes(id)
   }

   return <ComponentB handleLikeCallback={handleLikeCallback} likes={likes}/>
}

const ComponentB = ({handleLikeCallback, likes}) => 
    <button onclick={handleLikeCallback("123")}>{likes}</button>
```